# PreferencesViewControllerDelegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I found this in some example code I downloaded

```
#import "PreferencesViewController.h"
@class MetronomeView;

@interface MetronomeViewController : UIViewController <PreferencesViewControllerDelegate> {
    MetronomeView *metronomeView;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet MetronomeView *metronomeView;
- (IBAction)showInfo;   

@end
```

I tried to find information on PreferencesViewControllerDelegate, but didn't find much. What is this delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a custom view controller delegate protocol that **is** created by Apple, for use in the [Metronome sample project](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Metronome) (and I imagine others). The protocol declaration can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Metronome/Listings/Classes_PreferencesViewController_h.html), and how it's implemented can be seen [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Metronome/Listings/Classes_MetronomeViewController_m.html).

All it does is act as a delegate that monitors what happens to `PreferencesViewController`, the controller that manages the preferences view.

The protocol contains one method called `preferencesViewControllerDidFinish:`, which is implemented by `MetronomeViewController` like this. When the delegate receives a signal that the preferences view has been dismissed with the Done button, this is called to hide the view:

```
- (void)preferencesViewControllerDidFinish:(PreferencesViewController *)controller {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

A similar delegate called `FlipsideViewControllerDelegate` can be found in the Xcode iOS project template for a **Utility Application**.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a custom delegate created by whoever wrote the code you downloaded. It's not an Apple delegate, since it doesn't start with any of Apple's two-letter prefixes.